# Uninstall MKUSB

Tags: live-usb, uninstall, software-uninstall, mkusb

So I installed a few weeks ago mkusb to make a persistent live USB and now I don't need it anymore. But I can't find a way to uninstall it, it's not in the "Ubuntu Software" app, it's like there isn't. How can I completely delete it from my computer?

Comment: How did you install it?  NOrmally, `sudo apt remove mkusb 'mkusb-*'` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to remove mkusb

- **Standard**: If installed via the the PPA `ppa:mkusb/ppa`, the advice in the comment by Thomas Ward should do it.

  You may want to remove `usb-pack-efi` too (if installed)

  ```
  sudo apt remove mkusb 'mkusb-*' usb-pack-efi
  ```
- **Alternative**: If installed via a tarball, there is an installer script in the directory into which it was extracted, and you can use it to remove too:

  ```
  sudo ./dus-installer r  # remove
  ```

Comment: thank you, it worked

Comment: You are welcome @LiberoCarli :-)